# Powershell: find file, name file incrementally, then move file to specified location

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find files with the same name saved in various places on a computer, rename the file, and then move it to a designated location.

I.E

I have a test.txt file in random locations like:

```
\\accounting\2016\department1\test.txt
\\accounting\2017\department5\budget\test.txt
\\department2\financials\2020\test.txt
```

I want to take the test.txt file from each of those folders, rename it to test1 or test2 or basically anything so it doesn't overwrite, and then move them all to the same location like:

```
\\accounting\departmentbudgets\test1.txt
\\accounting\departmentbudgets\test2.txt 
\\accounting\departmentbudgets\test3.txt
```

This is what I have so far, it does find the test files and rename them incremintally, but it does not move them

```
Get-ChildItem c:\\* -filter test.txt -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('test{0:D1}.txt' -f $i++)} | %{Move-Item $_ -Path C:\Test}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Rename-Item` doesn't output anything by default, so there's no input for the block containing `Move-Item` to consume.

Use the `-PassThru` parameter switch to make `Rename-Item` return the renamed items:

```
... |%{ Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('test{0:D1}.txt' -f $i++) -PassThru } | ...
```